# salt cloud cant' set security group in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, salt-cloud

I'm launching windows ec2 instances using salt cloud. However I'm unable to set the security group. Instead of giving the instance the SG I specify, it gives you the 'default' security group.

Here's my cloud profile definition:

```
ec2_private_win_app1_c4.2xlarge:
provider: company-nonpod-us-east-1
image: ami-xxxxxx
size: c4.2xlarge
network_interfaces:
    - DeviceIndex: 0
PrivateIpAddresses:
    - Primary: True
#auto assign public ip (not EIP)
AssociatePublicIpAddress: False
SubnetId: subnet-xxxxx
SecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxx
block_device_mappings:
   - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
     Ebs.VolumeSize: 120
     Ebs.VolumeType: gp2
   - DeviceName: /dev/sdf
     Ebs.VolumeSize: 100
     Ebs.VolumeType: gp2
```

The yaml checks out when I parse it with an online yaml checker. What can I do differently to get the security group I specify instead of the 'default' security group?

Comment: I also wanted to comment on this, there have been some issues with the latest version of Salt-Cloud which involved parsing security groups at deploy time.  I'd recommend checking out their github issues (https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues) for anything that looks comparable, it might be a bug; I had issues with version 2016.11.1

Answer (score 0):

If the security group (SG) is not in the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) as the subnet you are specifying it will fail to apply the security group to the instance.